# UIViewController View rotates when rotation is set to portrait only

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, rotation, ios7

I am building my app for iOS 7. On a modal view controller, I have the following code for user interface orientation.

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}
```

However, when I rotate my device, it rotates with the device! I should add that this modal view is embedded in a UINavigationController as well.

I appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 1):

Found this post on Apple Dev forums.

https://devforums.apple.com/message/861976#861976

answers the question....if embedded in a UINavigationController, you must subclass the navigation controller to control device rotation that is different from that in your app settings.